# Wordpress theme not displaying (after updating to 3.1.3)

Tags: wordpress, themes

I'm building a custom Wordpress theme that was working but at some point the theme stopped loading in Wordpress and Wordpress switched back to the default TwentyTen.

I think it may have had to do with upgrading to 3.1.3. Any pointers on how to debug this?

Comment: Can you explain in more detail? Are all pages just blank? Or does some parts of the theme work?

Comment: Theme doesn't show in list of themes. Wordpress switched back to the default.

Comment: See my edit and try that. If none of those fixes the problem, we'll have to dig deeper.

Answer (score 1):

Turn on WP_DEBUG in config file

http://codex.wordpress.org/Editing_wp-config.php

Answer (score 0):

Aslo except for `WP_DEBUG` when themes are not showing up and just displays blank pages there is usually a quick fix:

- Change to another theme in the admin panel
- Change back to the theme that was not working
- If the theme has a hyphen in the name, remove it.
- Check so that all the files are in their proper place
- Check so that all the files are named right
- When the theme doesn't have a screenshot it's hard to spot, even though it's in the list. Check again carefully.